# File descriptor leak in nftw(FTW_CHDIR)?

Tags: linux, gcc, g++, posix, glibc

I am using the POSIX call `nftw()` for traversing a directory structure. The directory structure is flat - only 4 files and no subdirectories.

However when I call nftw() a lot of times on this flat directory then I get an error message after a while:

```
"too many open file handles".
```

It turned out that this happens when the flag `FTW_CHDIR` is used.

Would you agree that it is a bug in the Linux implementation of nftw() ?

**UPDATE**

A fix is now available in the glibc repositories.

here are some links to the source code I have used for testing:

- main.cpp: http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/attachment.cgi?id=4586&action=view
- Makefile: http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/attachment.cgi?id=4587&action=view

**UPDATE**

- MacOS-X is **also** hit by the bug
- Solaris9, Solaris10 and AIX 5.3 do **not** have the bug

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me it looks like there is really something wrong with the `nftw` implementation on linux.

I have filed a bug report, see [here](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11271)

**UPDATE**: A fix is available in the glibc repositories now.

Comment: wow, that was a quick fix - http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commit;h=247fdf2e2b798378d8aeaac1ee6f4ba0a49f31f3

Answer (score 0):

It has the same behaviour on Mac OS 10.6.2. So probably somehow part of the specification, though I don't see how exactly.

Comment: that's interesting. Our real world code is multiplatform - including MacOS. I'm going to check tomorrow if it happens within our MacOS application too.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Mac OS: bugreport submitted to Apple as radar #7640283. (No hyperlink possible, unfortunately.)

Comment: Given that Apple's BSD bits are mostly identical to FreeBSD's, I wonder if it's a bug inherited from there.